# Eclipse PDT Builder - What is it? How can I disable it?

Tags: eclipse, build, eclipse-pdt

I have a custom build-script for my site. I want to invoke this script whenever I press ctrl+b in eclipse.

I have configured a new builder seen at the top. While my own builder runs fine, eclipse also invokes "Validation" and "Script Builder". As far as I can tell these two do absolutely nothing, but take ages to complete.

[image: Eclipse PDT Builiders]

I have tried to simply disable them, but eclipse just creates them again as another instance. (hence the duplicates)

I have tried to add an exclusion to `*` for the PHP Build Path, but that didn't do anything.

What do "Validation" and "Script Builder" do exactly? Why do they take so long and above all: how can I disable them?

Answer (score 4):

The fact that these two builders are re-added after you disable them is a bug. Please file bug reports at bugs.eclipse.org. You will need to file separate bug reports as these two builders are maintained by different groups of people.

The Validation builder performs a variety of validation on artifacts in your project. You can see all validation that's performed under Validation property page in the same dialog. In that page, you can selectively disable the categories of validation that you don't want.

The Script Builder comes from PDT and presumably performs validation on the actual PHP artifacts. Outside of what you've already tried, I don't know of a way to disable it.

Comment: Thank you, but won't disabling those validators disable some of the code completion and bad syntax highlighting features?

Comment: Disabling validators will not disable completion, but it will disable flagging of errors.

Answer (score 1):

2 years later and I have the exact same problem with latest PDT.

This is what I did:

Validations:

- Right-click project
- Properties
- Validation
- Click checkbox "Enable project specific settings"
- Click checkbox "Suspend all validators"

Script Builder:

- Right-click project
- Properties-
- PHP Build Path
- remove all folders from "Source folders on build path:"
- or remove all but the ones you really want to be checked for syntax errors

Now "build" phase of PHP project is way shorter (like a half a second :)))

However, if you want to be able to navigate PHP source using Eclipse (like right-click on function and select "Open declaration" or pressing F3 on function name) then you need to leave folders in Script Builder with source you want to navigate. I had project with huge folders containing source of various frameworks and I removed those from "Source folders on build path:" and only left folder(s) with project source. That cut down build time to second or so.